# Verificar se o SQL Server está instalado C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, servidor

Estou a finalizar uma aplicação em C# que contém uma database em SQL Server. Como posso saber se o user tem o *SQL Server 2012 Express Local DB* instalado?

É possível verificar via `registry` em **x86** e **x64**?

Basicamente seria para alertar o usuário caso o *SQL Server 2012 Express Local DB* não estivesse instalado. Isto porque o instalador que estou a usar para fazer o setup da app, não contém pré-requisitos para *SQL Server 2012 Express Local DB*.

Comment: Tente verificar através deste registro: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\11.0`

Comment: A resposta pra sua pergunta ja foi dada , mas se for possível migre pro localdb 2016 que não precisa de nada instalado pra rodar  !

Comment: Ou seja não é necessário instalar SQL Server para quem for correr e não tiver instalado?

Answer (score 4):

Ele fica nesse caminho de registro, assim como todos as versoes do SQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilize o seguinte código para verificar se o registro existe:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\\Installed Versions");
if(key != null && key.GetSubKeyNames().Count() > 0)
{
    //existe!
}
```

Isso porque pode ser a versão 11 ou 12... etc.

Comment: Mas com isto não irá verificar para x86 e x64, correcto?

Comment: Ver a resposta do @Dener Carvalho para maiores detalhes sobre isso.

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma de verificar se o SQL Server Local DB esta instalado é através do registro `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions` já citado na resposta do @daniloloko, entretanto, é necessario especificar para o `RegistryKey` se o sistema é `x86` ou `x64`.

Podemos fazer isto através da propriedade `Is64BitOperatingSystem` da classe [Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para determinar se o sistema é de 64bit ou 32bit, em seguida especificar qual visualização do registro deve ser usada `RegistryView.Registry64;` ou `RegistryView.Registry32;` no objeto `RegistryView`.

Segue o software que verifica se o SQL Server Local BD esta instalado:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace SQLServerLocalDBInstalledExemplo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryView registryViewArchitecture;

            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                registryViewArchitecture = RegistryView.Registry64;
            else
                registryViewArchitecture = RegistryView.Registry32;

            using (RegistryKey registryKeyLocalMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryViewArchitecture)) 
            {
                RegistryKey registryKey = registryKeyLocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions", false);

                if (registryKey != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL Server Local DB instalado.");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL Server Local DB não esta instalado.");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Para manipular o registro é necessário adicionar o namespace [Microsoft.Win32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.win32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), veja também que foi necessário utilizar o método `OpenBaseKey` da classe `RegistryKey`, este [método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) permite abrir uma nova `RegistryKey` que representa a chave solicitada na máquina local com o modo de exibição especificado no objeto `registryViewArchitecture`.

Fontes:
[Check if SQL Server is installed on a machine through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443001/check-if-sql-server-is-installed-on-a-machine-through-c-sharp)
[SQL2012 LocalDB: how to check in c# if it is currently installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628316/sql2012-localdb-how-to-check-in-c-sharp-if-it-is-currently-installed)

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente e detalhada solução.